# jQuery, convert css classes into an object

Tags: jquery

Im trying to convert normal css markup into an object:

```
.btn {
  border-radius: 28px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

so it becomes

```
var btn = {
  "border-radius": "28px",
  "padding": "10px 20px 10px 20px",
  "border":"1px solid #000",
};
```

then I can use it with jquery css function to style other elements

```
$(".el").css(btn);
```

I have tried using both `JSON.parse()`, and `JSON.stringify()`, but no success.

Comment: can u reproduce the problem in stacksnippet?

Comment: JSON.stringify will not work because it's a string and not am object.

Comment: `normal css markup` ? Your first variable not an normal css, It's an invalid string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you simply do:

```
$(".el").addClass("btn");
```

Still if you want to proceed with the approach you suggested, then you can do something like this:

```js
var btn = `{
  border-radius: 28px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}`;

formattedBtn = btn.split("\n");
/* Remove first element and last element as they are 
{ and } */
formattedBtn.pop();
formattedBtn.shift();

var obj = {};
formattedBtn.forEach(
  (el) => {
    let proerty = el.split(":");
    obj[proerty[0].trim()] = proerty[1].trim().replace(/;/g, "");
  }
)

console.log(obj);

$(function(){
  $("#but").css(obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="but">My Button</button>
```

Comment: Try with `$(".el").css(btn);` of course it's not working.

Comment: @Pedram yea forgot to remove the `;`. Fixed now, check the updated snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var btn = '{border-radius: 28px;padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;border:1px solid #000}';
    btn = btn.replace(/[{}]/gi, " ").trim(); // remove '{' and '}'

    var my_result = [], temp;
    $.each(btn.split(";"), function(i, css_prop){
        temp = css_prop.split(":");
        my_result[temp[0]] = temp[1];
    });

    console.log('my_result',my_result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```